# SQL Server CASE with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to figure out how to do a SQL Server CASE command with multiple conditions.

I'm trying to use the conditions

```
If column_a = 'test' AND column_b IS NULL OR (column_b IS NOT NULL AND Column_c = Column_d) OR Column_e >= 480 THEN 'OK'
ELSE 'CHECK'
END
```

So broken down what I'm trying to say is:

```
If column_a = 'test' AND column_b IS NULL return 'OK'
OR If column_a = 'test' AND (column_b IS NOT NULL AND Column_c = Column_d) OR Column_e >= 480 THEN 'OK'
```

So what I wrote for the statement is

```
CASE WHEN column_a = 'test' AND column_b IS NULL OR (column_b IS NOT NULL AND Column_c = Column_d) OR Column_e >= 480 THEN 'OK'
ELSE 'CHECK'
END
```

I'm not getting any errors just not getting the desired results.  Is that the correct order of multiple AND OR statements in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
case 
    when column_a = 'test'
    and (column_b is null 
        or
        (column_b is not null and column_c = column_d))
        or column_e >=480
        then 'OK'
```

or show some sample data and expected outcome so we can get a better understanding of what its doing

Comment: Thanks dbajr - I tried it and it worked for me.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I would break it down a bit different. I would suggest something like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN column_a='test' AND column_b IS NULL
    THEN 'OK'
    WHEN column_a = 'test' AND (column_b IS NOT NULL AND Column_c = Column_d) OR Column_e >= 480
    THEN 'OK'
    ELSE 'CHECK'
END
```

Comment: Thanks Arion your suggestion was useful much appreciated